# Storing binary data in Google Secret Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I'm using [Google Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) for the first time to store some binary data. When I access the secret, it seems to have a different encoding or format.

The actual data is a certificate bundle, but I've been able to reproduce the issue using smaller binary data. Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a file with binary data:

   ```
   echo -e -n '\xed\xfe' > secret.txt
   ```
2. Create the secret and version:

   ```
   gcloud secrets create "my-secret" \
     --data-file ./secret.txt \
     --replication-policy "automatic"
   ```
3. Access the secret and save the result to a file:

   ```
   gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret "my-secret" > result.txt
   ```
4. Compare the two files:

   ```
   od -t x1 secret.txt  # ed fe
   od -t x1 result.txt  # 3f 3f 0a
   ```

Why is the result different? Do I have to do something extra to get Google Secret Manager to work with binary data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) stores data exactly as given. Unfortunately there was a bug in the `gcloud` CLI tool that was adding an additional newline character to the end of a response.

This bug was [fixed in gcloud v288.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes). Please make sure you are using v288.0.0 or higher.

If you're concerned about local encoding issues, you should acquire the raw JSON response instead. This response will include the base64-encoded secret payload, which is much safer for transport:

```
gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret "my-secret" --format "json"
```

You can use a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the JSON on the command line. Note, the secret payload data is base64-encoded, so you will need to decode the value prior to using it.

```
gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret "my-secret" --format "json" | \
  jq -r .payload.data | \
  base64 --decode > results_binary.txt
```

Verify:

```
od -t x1 results_binary.txt  # ed fe
```

Comment: If you don't have `jq` installed in  your environment, you can use the --format parameter to gcloud to parse out the field in the json that you want.  See this doc from Google for more info [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with).